# Why EFCore 6 does not work on iOS anymore?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, xamarin.ios, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 6 on an iOS application I built using `.net6`. It used to work on older versions (both EF & .net) but now I am getting the following error:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper dynamic-method) AccountTableEntity

object:Thunk1ret_AccountTableEntity_QueryContext_DbDataReader_ResultContext_SingleQueryResultCoordinator (System.Func`2<object[], object>,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext,System.Data.Common.DbDataReader,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ResultContext,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryResultCoordinator)' while running in aot-only mode. 

See https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.
```

I am not sure why it would be failing considering how simple the use case is. Here is the TableEntity:

```
[Table("Accounts")]
internal sealed class AccountTableEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the data.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("Data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ID of the owner of the account.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("UserSid")]
    public string UserSid { get; set; }

    public AccountTableEntity()
    {
        UserSid = string.Empty;
        Data = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <param name="accountTableEntity"></param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    /// Thrown if:
    /// - The instance of <see cref="AccountTableEntity" /> is not specified.
    /// </exception>
    public AccountTableEntity(AccountTableEntity accountTableEntity)
    {
        Guard.Argument(accountTableEntity, nameof(accountTableEntity)).NotNull();

        UserSid = accountTableEntity.UserSid;
        Data = accountTableEntity.Data;
    }
}
```

And here is the call :

```
DbContext db = ...;

foreach (AccountTableEntity account in db.Accounts.ToList())
{
   //
}
```

By looking at the callstack and my pretty straightforward use case, I am getting the feeling that EFCore 6 does not work on iOS anymore.

**Question**

Can Entity Framework Core 6 work on iOS and if yes, why is it failing now with an `System.ExecutionEngineException`?

Comment: Actually I'm impressed that this was worked before. EF Core uses `LambdaExpression.Compile` everywhere, but iOS has limitation that generated code cannot be executed. Probably better to create issue in EF Core`s GitHub repository.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, I agree, especially after seeing the callback. I was using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4 and Xamarin.iOS and it did work (after adding --linkskip mtouch options).

Comment: iOS don't allow JIT mode , try to raise the issue on github for better support : https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Thanks! I am switching to SQLite instead; it seems more appropriate to such environment.

Comment: Correct, SQLite is more suitable for mobile app .

Answer (score 1):

Edit `.cproj` of your maui app

```
    <!--IOS RELEASE-->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <!--to be able to use EF core dynamic stuff-->
        <MtouchExtraArgs>--interpreter</MtouchExtraArgs>
        <UseInterpreter>True</UseInterpreter>
        <EnableAssemblyILStripping>false</EnableAssemblyILStripping>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Delete `bin` `obj` and rebuild

I can see no performance impact and we have successfully published our app compiled with theses settings to AppStore.

Comment: I did this and it caused my app to crash on startup in release mode. This was because I had set EnableAssemblyILStripping to true. Using `/p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false` on my pipeline solved the crash issue and the app worked perfectly with EFCore.

Comment: thank you @BurkusCat, completed the answer for your case